# c# referencing a label from another method

Tags: c#, methods, reference, windows-forms-designer

I want if mouse leave the visible status change to false,but I get this error message:
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'e' of 'Form1.Repair_MouseLeave(object, EventArgs, Label)' 
How shoudl I fix it?

```
    private void Repair_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label RepairText = new Label();
        RepairText = new Label();
        RepairText.Location = new Point(161, 12);
        RepairText.Text = "This what the program will do";
        this.Controls.Add(RepairText);
        RepairText.AutoSize = true;
        Repair_MouseLeave(RepairText);

    }

    private void Repair_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e,Label repairtext)
    {
    repairtext.Visible = false;

    }
```

Comment: you should bind to the events.

Comment: First of all, remove the `Label repairtext`parameter from your `Repair_MouseLeave` method signature. Make RepairText an instance member of your form, or, give your label a name before adding it to the controls collection and then find it in `Repair_MouseLeave` using `Controls.Find()`

Comment: Is it really feasible to create and add a new label to your form every time mouse leaves a control? (No.)

Comment: You should not try to invoke the event handler yourself. `Repair_MouseLeave(RepairText);` is wrong. Even if you successfully call this method, your repairText label will not be visible event for a fraction of a nanosecond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we need to set our event handlers for the MouseHover and MouseLeave methods for the `Repair` control. I am assuming you know how to do this. Still, 
binding to the events of Repair control can be achieved using the Properties window of your Form in design mode. Set event handlers to both `MouseHover` and `MouseLeave`.

As far as I can see, you are trying to display a label with some text when the mouse is hovering over this Repair control and want to hide it when the mouse leaves it. But you are handling it incorrectly. First of all, calling `MouseLeave` from inside `MouseHover` would immediately hide your new label and it would not be displayed at all.

And your method signature for `Repair_MouseLeave` is also incorrect. A standard event handler takes two parameters: `(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Implement your event handlers like the following, having the new label `repairText` as an instance member of your class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Label repairText;

    private void Repair_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(repairText == null)
        {
            repairText = new Label();
            repairText.Location = new Point(161, 12);
            repairText.Text = "This what the program will do";
            repairText.AutoSize = true;
            this.Controls.Add(repairText);
        }
        repairText.Visible = true;
    }

    private void Repair_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(repairText != null)
        {
            repairText.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```